How can I use the sqllab/execute endpoint of a Superset Instance from local?
I have a Superset Instance with a connection to a Postgres Database.
When I execute a query through the Superset U, it works as expected.
The Superset UI makes a request to the /sqllab/execute/ endpoint and gets the result.
I'm also trying to execute queries on postgres through superset using the python code present below.
class SupersetAPI:
    def __init__(self, creds: SupersetCreds):
        self.creds = creds
        self.security_endpoint = f"{self.creds.url}/api/v1/security"
        self.auth_endpoint = f"{self.security_endpoint}/login"
        self.csrf_token_endpoint = f"{self.security_endpoint}/csrf_token/"
        self.dbs_endpoint = f"{self.creds.url}/api/v1/database/"
        self.sqllab_endpoint = f"{self.creds.url}/api/v1/sqllab/"
        self.execute_endpoint = f"{self.sqllab_endpoint}execute/"
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.auth_token = self.authenticate()
        self.csrf_token = self.fetch_csrf_token()

    def _form_headers(self, header_fields: Dict = {}):
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {self.auth_token}",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-Csrftoken": self.csrf_token,  # Include the CSRF token in the request headers
            **header_fields
        }
        return headers

    def execute_sql_query(self, database_id: int, sql_query: str):
        """Executes a SQL query on the specified database."""
        headers = self._form_headers({
            "Referer": self.sqllab_endpoint # https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/16398#issuecomment-1184678574)
        })
        payload = {
            "client_id": str(uuid.uuid4()),
            "ctas_method": "TABLE",
            "database_id": database_id,
            "expand_data": True,
            "json": True,
            "runAsync": False,
            "select_as_cta": False,
            "sql": sql_query,
        }

        response = self.session.post(self.execute_endpoint, headers=headers, json=payload)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Ensure we got a successful response
        response_json = response.json()
        return response_json

The execute_sql_query gets a 500 response from the Superset Server. The body contains '{"errors":[{"error_type":"GENERIC_DB_ENGINE_ERROR","message":"Create failed"}]} '. I can't figure out why this is happening.
Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

I switched the client Id field to be a random 10 character string (ascii letters only) and queries started executing. Earlier I was using a uuidv4.
Found this by messing around with the original request on postman.
